# Git cherry-Pick a batch of commits from a file

Tags: git

I'm attempting to cherry-pick a batch of commits from my master branch and get them into their own branch. I have all my commit hashes in a file (called output.txt) and i'm attempting to pipe this to git cherry-pick. Here is the command i came up with:

tail -r ~/outfile.txt | git cherry-pick -n --stdin

yet this string fails if there is a merge conflict, i would rather have something that hangs when i hit a merge conflict so i can fix it and continue along

any ideas?

Comment: What's `-r` for the tail command? I cannot find it in the manpage

Comment: its to reverse the list, i grabbed the list from log and it printed from most recent to least recent, So i reverse the list to process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building upon knittl's answer:

```
while read line; do
    git cherry-pick -n "$line" || exit 1
done < outfile.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

What about a loop?

```
while read line; do
  git cherry-pick -n "$line"
done < outfile.txt
```

Comment: Nope, that still hangs on merge conflict: 
error: could not apply 2ad0da0...
hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
hint: with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'
hint: and commit the result with 'git commit'
(FILENAME): unmerged (df123cbb5a9f8661fda9bb00f336988d683ace3a)