# Git - Log commits of dev except which are cherry-picked into main

Tags: git, version-control, git-merge, git-log

I have `dev` and `main` branches. Some commits go to the `dev` branch and then some of the `dev` branch commits go into the `main` branch. Which means, there are several commits in `dev` branch which are not submitted/cherry-picked in `main` branch at any given time.

I wonder if there is a way to log all `dev` commits which are new or which are not cherry-picked into `main`.

I tried with,

```
$git log main..dev
$git log dev..main
```

but they don't serve my purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rebase in your local clone of the repo your `dev` branch on top of `main`: any commit already cherry-picked would *not* be replayed on top of `main`.

Or, simpler:

```
git cherry -v main dev
```

This would show all of the commits which are contained within `dev`, but *not* in `main`.
See "[Git log to get commits only for a specific branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14848274/6309)".

Comment: I was preparing a list with --pretty option while logging, but cherry has no such option. :( is there any workaround. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan you can pipe the result of the `git cherry` command to a `git log -1`, in order to display each commit found as you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot @VonC

Comment: I see `git log` does not read from stdin (https://stackoverflow.com/a/37325995/1084174) . I am unable to pipe into `git log`. Even using `xargs` it does not work. `git cherry main dev | grep ^- | tr -d "-" | xargs git log -1` it always shows last single commit. How can I solve it?

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan Can you redirect the ouput of `git cherry` to a file? And then https://stackoverflow.com/a/12521546/6309 (replacing `git cherry` by `git log`)

Comment: I can but that would be complicated for my developers. I was searching for a better workaround as an PI member. Any idea except creating files as it would be frequent.

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan I understand. Yet, that can be scripted, and deployed as a command for the developers to use.